# Phaser 3 clickable sprite can't start scene

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I have created a clickable sprite in Phaser 3 using typescript.
I want to change scenes when the sprite is clicked:

```
export class BMO extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {

    constructor(scene) {
        super(scene, 100,150, "bmo")
        this.scene.add.existing(this)
        this.setInteractive()

        this.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
            this.scene.start('GameOver');
        }, this);
    }
}
```

When clicking on the sprite in the running game I get:

> this.scene.start is not a function

The exact same code does work when it's inside a scene instead of a sprite:

```
export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super({key: "GameScene"})
    }

    create(): void {
        this.input.once('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
            this.scene.start('GameOver');
        }, this);
    }
}
```

How can I change scenes from a clickable sprite in Phaser 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call method `start` on `scene` property on `Scene` object like You did on second example:

```
this.scene.scene.start('GameOver');
```

`scene` property on `Scene` object refers to `ScenePlugin`, look at the [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html#scene)

Comment: Thanks this works. I find the docs somewhat unreadable. For some reason, IntelliSense doesn't work for me inside a `this.on('pointer down')` handler inside a sprite, so that's why I couldn't see that scene has another scene property.

Comment: I agree, docs require some extra work.However, dev logs saved me few times - highly recommend ( https://phaser.io/phaser3/devlog )